# sniff telephone line data using old modem

Tags: telephone, data

i have an old modem that i'd like to use to sniff the data going out on the telephone line. i realize that i can't use the computers serial port to process the data as they are real slow. Can anyone help me [i am pretty clueless] on the basic idea behind what would be required to accomplish this lowest cost please.

Comment: Why is this so strongly downvoted? Ian -says- he is pretty clueless, so it shouldn't be a problem that what he is asking can not be done.

Comment: A major challenge will be to get the modem to simply demodulate without first participating in a speed negotiation.  You may need the ability to modify the firmware or put it in an obscure engineering test mode.  Consider a sampling interface and software DSP demodulator.

Comment: While it's clear what you're trying to accomplish, it's difficult to comprehensively answer your question. It would require a complete tutorial, and it's not possible in the limited space of an answer. Try to make it less broad.

Comment: @Bobbi: It is not strongly downvoted, +3 -4 currently.  However, I can see the point due to the sloppy writing.  You don't have to know much English to know that the first letter of every sentence is capitalized, and that the word "I" is always capitalized.  Showing us this level of disrespect isn't going to win you any favors.  Even aside from the disrespect, this is engineering, where neatness and attention to detail count, although I suspect that's not the main reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I see your point. I just wish the newbies were more encouraged/inclined to improve their questions.

Comment: @Bobbi: We shouldn't have to tell someone basic stuff like capitalize the first letter of each sentence.  That has nothing to do with lack of electronics knowledge.  That is just disrespect, basically saying *"Eh, these people don't matter, they'll take whatever slop I throw at them"*.  You wouldn't hand in a homework assignment like this.  Why should we get less respect than the professor, especially since this is such a easy thing to do?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you narrow what you want a lot I think what you want is totally impossible. There is simply too much data that can go over your telephone lines.

At the moment my telephone line carries

- POTS (plain old telphone - the common analog telephone signal)
- Internet traffic (ADSL)

and within that internet traffic

- the digital TV signal that my son is watching
- and all other fancy things that can go over internet, including VOIP

Funny isn't it, the telephone wires are (mis) used to carry internet traffic, which is in turn (mis) used to carry speach in the form of VOIP!

The only thing your old modem might be able to decode is exactly the signal it was made for - probably 38k4 data-over-POTS. The good point is that the datarate of that information is something your computer will be able to cope with :)

---

Funny, this answer was downvoted twice! I don't mind this at all, but I'd like to know why (wrong answer? not answering the question? should not have been answered at all?)